# Use custom method controller for a custom route

Tags: symfony4, api-platform.com

I created a custom controller for PUT item operation. I used the `_invoke` method to make the default action but I tried to used a custom method to a second PUT action on the same item.

---

I tried this configurations without success.

```
*         "activate"={
*             "method"="PUT",
*             "path"="/safety_rooms/{id}/activate",
*             "requirements"={"id"="\d+"},
*             "controller"=SafetyRoomPutItem::activeRoom,
*          },
```

but I get `[Semantical Error] Couldn't find constant App\Controller\SafetyRoomPutItem::activeRoom, class App\Entity\SafetyRoom.`

---

I tried this configurations without success.

```
*         "activate"={
*             "method"="PUT",
*             "path"="/safety_rooms/{id}/activate",
*             "requirements"={"id"="\d+"},
*             "controller"=SafetyRoomPutItem::class.activeRoom,
*          },
```

but I get `[Syntax Error] Expected Doctrine\Common\Annotations\DocLexer::T_CLOSE_CURLY_BRACES, got '.' at position 1274 in class App\Entity\SafetyRoom.`

---

I tried this configurations without success.

```
*         "activate"={
*             "method"="PUT",
*             "path"="/safety_rooms/{id}/activate",
*             "requirements"={"id"="\d+"},
*             "controller"=SafetyRoomPutItem::class(activeRoom),
*          },
```

---

I tried this configurations without success.

```
*         "activate"={
*             "method"="PUT",
*             "path"="/safety_rooms/{id}/activate",
*             "requirements"={"id"="\d+"},
*             "controller"=SafetyRoomPutItem::class:activeRoom,
*          },
```

---

I tried this configurations without success.

```
*         "activate"={
*             "method"="PUT",
*             "path"="/safety_rooms/{id}/activate",
*             "requirements"={"id"="\d+"},
*             "controller"=SafetyRoomPutItem:activeRoom,
*          },
```

---

I tried this configurations without success.

```
*         "activate"={
*             "method"="PUT",
*             "path"="/safety_rooms/{id}/activate",
*             "requirements"={"id"="\d+"},
*             "controller"=[SafetyRoomPutItem::class, "activeRoom"],
*          },
```

but I get `[Syntax Error] Expected PlainValue, got '[' at position 1250 in class App\Entity\SafetyRoom.`

---

Comment: See the [docs on alternative method for controllers](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/controllers/#alternative-method)
below "Alternatively, you can also use a traditional Symfony controller"

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure to have you full qualified namespace declared in use of your class:
`use App\Controller\SafetyRoomPutItem\SafetyRoomPutItem` ?